# ASP.NET - Make gridview (DataTable source) refresh after new row is added (triggered by timer)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, timer, datatable

I have a method that is triggered every minute by a timer, and this method adds a row to a DataTable.  There is a GridView on the page which has this DataTable as its course.  Every time a row is added, I DataBind() - the new row shows up in the DataTable (I can see it in the debugger), but not on the GridView.

I won't overwhelm you with code, but I'll try to show everything relevant.

Here are the **declarations for the timer and the DataTable** source:

```
static DataTable logTable;
System.Timers.Timer timeoutTimer;
```

Here's what happens on **Page_Load**:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (logTable == null)
        {
            logTable = new DataTable();
            logTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Timestamp", typeof(string)));
            logTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Type", typeof(string)));
            logTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Message", typeof(string)));
        }
    }
```

Here's how the **timer gets initialized** (it DOES fire successfully every minute):

```
    StopTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);

    timeoutTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(60000);
    timeoutTimer.Interval = 60000;
    timeoutTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(RunningStatusesTick);
    timeoutTimer.Start();

    GC.KeepAlive(timeoutTimer);
```

Here's the **tick method**:

```
    private void RunningStatusesTick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e){

        try
        {
            string info = GetRawInfo();
            recordResults(info);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Error thrown?  Catch it and record it.
            recordResults(ex.Message, true);
        }
    }
```

Here's the **method that adds new rows to the DataTable** (and does the DataBind()):

```
    private void recordResults(string ResultText, bool IsError = false)
    {
        DataRow logRow = logTable.NewRow();
        logRow["Timestamp"] = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
        logRow["Type"] = (IsError ? "ERROR" : "INFO");
        logRow["Message"] = ResultText;
        logTable.Rows.Add(logRow);

        gvLogTable.DataSource = null;
        gvLogTable.DataSource = logTable;
        gvLogTable.DataBind();
    }
```

And finally, here are the aspx tags with the gridview:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView runat="server" id="gvLogTable"></asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Things I've already tried:

- Putting the DataSource = null line before the lines where the new row is created
- Adding a Response.Redirect (didn't work because the method was triggered by a timer)
- Creating a temporary table to use for the datasource (set to the static table's information)

Thanks so much in advance!  :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your rebind is incorrect.  In the recordResults() function, your last three lines are as follows:

```
gvLogTable.DataSource = null;
gvLogTable.DataSource = logRow;
gvLogTable.DataBind();
```

I think you want to be binding to `logTable`, not `logRow`.

Alternately, have you tried using [BindingListCollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindinglistcollectionview.aspx) and the associated [Refresh()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindinglistcollectionview.aspx) method?  I'm not sure if it will solve your problems, but it might be worth a look.

Comment: Whoops!  When I was rolling back some changes I'd made so I'd have something clearer to show here, I accidentally put that in.  Thanks for catching my mistake.  I'll give the BindingListCollectionView a try right now.

Comment: Hi again - I've been trying to figure out how to use BindingListCollectionView for this, but to no avail.  I can't figure out how to use it as a tag, or use it with a gridview (or whatever else it needs to be used with).  Could you please show me roughly how it can be used on the aspx and code-behind sides?  Thanks very much!

Comment: Here's a link to someone using it that might help you: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/2ae4e31a-99ad-4867-8386-f4f27dfe4be5